# 'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddJsonFile'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following error:

> Program.cs(15,72): error CS1061: 'ConfigurationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddJsonFile' and no accessible extension method 'AddJsonFile' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfigurationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly

The project is a dotnet core app, console application, using Azure Search SDK

The line of error is below:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using Microsoft.Azure.Search;
using Microsoft.Azure.Search.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Spatial;

namespace DemoSearchIndexer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
            ...
```

Answer (score 238, accepted):

The [`AddJsonFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.jsonconfigurationextensions?view=aspnetcore-2.2) extension method is available in NuGet:

- [`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json)

When building an ASP.NET Core application, which usually references `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` (or, historically, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`), you get this "for free".

When building a console application, or something that doesn't reference the metapackages, you need an explicit reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`.

Comment: You'll need to add Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json NuGet package. If you're on .net 7 or are trying .net 8 (still RC when I wrote this), it might not shown on the Manage Package for Solution browser. Just use Package Manager console and type : NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json -Version 7.0.0 (replace 7.0.0 with same version as your Microsoft Extension Configuration for other version) Hope this saves some time for those who experienced the same issue as me

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
```

Adding this Nuget Package in your solution will help you use ConfigurationBuilder like this:

```
IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

Answer (score -3):

You also have to set appsettings file properties to "copy always".

See [this](https://jd-bots.com/2021/06/30/fixed-the-configuration-file-appsettings-json-was-not-found-and-is-not-optional/) for more infos.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I always forget that, thanks. (it is not directly related to the question, but just something people forget)